# How to serve static assets from a private bucket via GCP GLB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I have a Global External Load balancer in GCP, that we use to serve the static assets(images, css files etc)

All the static assets are in GCS bucket.

If the GCS bucket is private, we get `AccessDenied`. I cant keep the bucket public as well.

Signed URL is also not an option cause the assets URL cannot change with time.

Is there a way where I can keep the GCS bucket private and use it to serve static assets via a cloud CDN?

If Public is the only way, can I have sort some ACLs where only Google IPs can access the bucket?

Comment: Why do you need to protect the static assets? Are they only available for some authenticated users?

Comment: so the paths are predictable of all the assets and hence from security point of view wanted to limit the surface area.

Comment: I don't like the ACL solution, it's too hard and weak to maintain. It's also not recommended by Google Cloud (prefer Uniform permission buckets). For me, there is a design issue: Put in a public bucket all the public assets. For those that require a secure access (authenticated user) you must have a backend that check the authentication and serve these private resources (directly from the code, or through a signedURL from a private bucket).

Comment: @Nagri Have you seen the updated answer, let us know if you required any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there are 4 different ways to serve content via Cloud CDN using a private bucket:

1. tokenized access: I understand that this isn't very desirable, but it is an option. I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@reisfeld/google-cloud-cdn-best-practice-ed643558120e) on how to do this.
2. [token proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cdn-auth-proxy): this deploys a Cloud Run instance that will deploy an ephemeral token for you so you can access a private GCS bucket.
3. Leverage v4 token signing: this option uses the the newer v4 token signing process. It is generally used for accessing a private AWS S3 bucket, but you can leverage the built-in S3 compatibility model within GCS to dynamically generate a v4 token. Here is a [link](https://medium.com/@thetechbytes/private-gcs-bucket-access-through-google-cloud-cdn-430d940ebad9) to a blog post that tells you how to do it.
4. Engineering hack: you can contact Google technical support and request them to "enable private bucket access".  What this does is it desensitizes the GCS authentication system and won't check for a token in the private bucket. A service account name is generated where you can add IAM read permissions to the service account.

Each of these methods has pros and cons. My personal favorite at the moment is the v4 token option. It leverages the native functionality so no additional costs of running a Cloud Run proxy, you don't need to actually deploy a Web server to generate an ephemeral token, and you aren't hard wiring something.

Comment: If you wanted to go a completely different approach, you might want to consider Media CDN and it has built-in support for accessing private buckets using a service account: https://cloud.google.com/media-cdn/docs/origins?hl=en#private-storage-buckets

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't include a way to set up a Load Balancer with a private Cloud Storage bucket as the backend. However, by [adding Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/securing-gcs-static-website) to access the private bucket objects, you can work around this issue.

you might want to instead organize your bucket to only contain objects intended to be publicly accessible, you can restrict access to a certain IP range using VPC Service Control.This allows you to define a service perimeter that includes your project's GCS service and add an access level to allow access from the IPs you want, or to [implement ACLs for each object in your website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#sharing).

You can check this blog posts on [Limiting Access to Google Cloud Storage by IP address](https://medium.com/google-cloud/limit-bucket-access-in-google-cloud-storage-by-ip-address-d59029cab9c6) by Quinlan Jung and [Serving static files using Google Cloud CDN + Storage Bucket](https://medium.com/techintoo/serving-static-files-using-google-cloud-cdn-storage-bucket-db1287cb5e40) by Subhajit Dutta

Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73945526/accessing-private-google-bucket-through-google-cdn-w-o-signed-urls) Accessing private google bucket through google CDN w/o signed URLs

Comment: The first solution you are proposing uses `Signed URL` I cant use those.
The second solution works at project level, I dont want that either.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73945526/accessing-private-google-bucket-through-google-cdn-w-o-signed-urls) Accessing private google bucket through google CDN w/o signed URLs.